# rails, query via url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I created my app using the following scaffold

```
    rails generate scaffold server hostname:string
    rails generate scaffold template remote_template_id:integer remote_template_name:string server:belongs_to
```

I edited the routes to be nested

```
      resources :servers do 
            resources :templates
      end
```

Now I edited stuff around and my app is working great. However, as this is back-end and not customer facing, I wish to able to run a query such as this, where 'templatename' at the end is an arbitrary string

```
    http://127.0.0.1:3000/servers/1/templates/find_by_remote_template_name/templatename
```

Essentially, be able to search using the column name remote_template_name .

What would be the best way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `routes.rb` file:

```
resources :servers do
  resources :templates
  match 'templates/search/:template_name', to: 'templates#search', via: :get
end
```

Then you should be able to query `http://localhost:3000/servers/1/templates/search/whatever` which will route to the `#search` action of the `TemplatesController` passing in `params[:template_name]`

Comment: Please read my response again. You haven't got the `routes.rb` or URL quite as I put it. Also, since you're passing in the controller name not ID, you need to be searching for the template using that. `.find_by_name(params[:template_name])` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Special Thanks to Jon.

Solution: the correct routing had to be set and the search function in the controller needed some tweaking

routes.rb:

```
    resources :servers do
      resources :templates
      match 'templates/search/:template_name', to: 'templates#search', via: :get
    end
```

And I had to add in the column name that is being searched in the TemplatesController

```
    def search
            @template = @server.templates.where("remote_template_name = ?", params[:template_name])
            respond_to do |format |
                    format.html 
                    format.json { render json: @template }
            end
    end
```